# How to sign up a user and verify their phone number with Cognito User Pools in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So far I can only find how to do this in the AWS documentation in objective c, not swift. I am successfully creating users in the User Pool in swift with the following code:

```
let userPool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "myApp")

var name = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
name.name = "name"
name.value = nameEntry.text

var phone = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
phone.name = "phone_number"
phone.value = "+1" + phoneNumberEntry.text!

var email = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
email.name = "email"
email.value = emailEntry.text

userPool.signUp("goats", password: passwordEntry.text!, userAttributes: [name, phone, email], validationData: nil)
```

Doing the above code creates a user in the Cognito User Pool as expected.

Furthermore, the above code successfully sends a verification code to the phone number provided. However, I have been unable to then successfully pass this verification code back to AWS and verify the phone number. I have tried both of the following lines after the user has been created in the User Pool, neither of which are changing the phone number to being verified:

```
user.verifyAttribute("phone_number", code: verificationEntry.text!)
user.confirmSignUp(verificationEntry.text!)
```

for what it's worth I am setting the user variable to the following, after the user has signed up:

```
self.user = userPool.getUser()
```

None of this is working and AWS's objective c documentation isn't helpful. Any ideas on how to verify the user's phone number?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `userPool.getUser(username: String)`, not `userPool.getUser()`.

In your case:

```
self.user = userPool.getUser(nameEntry.text)
```

Otherwise, you might get following error.

```
[Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"2 validation errors detected: Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+"}
```

Answer (score 0):

After signup, you should call confirm signup to confirm the user and mark the phone/email (where you got the code).

You can do get user to confirm whether the attribute was marked as verified.

P.S.: If you are having issues please PM me your user pool id, user name and signup time frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the user to whom the verfication code was sent. So use getUser() with the username. Then you call confirmSignUp().

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBAction func confirmButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if confirmationCodeTextField.text != nil {
        let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
        let user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser = pool.getUser("userName")
        user.confirmSignUp(confirmationCodeTextField.text!).continue(with: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), withSuccessBlock: { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserConfirmSignUpResponse>) -> Any? in

            if task.error != nil {
                // Error
            } else {
                // handle the success response
            }
            return nil
        })
    } else {
        // Ask user to enter the confirmation code.
    }
}
```

The above method will help you to **confirm the user sign up**. While getting the user you must specify the "user Name". This code is written in **swift 3**.